# How to use a script output as a value in .gitconfig?

Tags: bash, git, config, digital-signature

I want to sign my git commits with my Yubikey, but only if my Yubikey is present. I have a script, `yubikey-present.sh` that I can run that will output `true` if the yubikey is present and `false` otherwise.

Is there a way to run this script and use the output as the value for `commit.gpgsign` in `~/.gitconfig`? I've tried:

```
[commit]
  gpgsign = !`/path/to/yubikey-present.sh`
```

But it tells me:

```
fatal: bad boolean config value '!`/path/to/yubikey-present.sh`' for 'commit.gpgsign'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try writing a hook script that changes your configuration before each commit. `.git/hooks/pre-commit` is a hook script that is run before each commit. Try a script that contains this line:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

git config commit.gpgsign "$(/path/to/yubikey-present.sh)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure Git rereads `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config` during `git commit`. Did you verify it does and notices the config changes?

Comment: @phd - Yes, I just tested it. After `git commit`, the change to the config happens before git opens the commit message editor.

Comment: Nice, thank your for testing and reporting!

Comment: This works in that it changes the config file, but even if `commit.gpgsign` is `false`, it wants me to insert the card with a specific id. If I remove my `signingkey` from the global config, then it tries to use a default private key. For some reason, it continues to want to sign commits even if `commit.gpgsign` is `false`.

Comment: Hm, so I think the issue I was having was that this writes the config before the commit message editor is opened, but I believe it is _after_ the configuration for that particular commit has already been read. In other words, it will take effect only for the _following_ commit, unless I'm incorrect?

Comment: Does it behave differently when you set the config manually, then commit?